# If $(a_{2n} -a_n)$ is convergent to zero then $(a_n)$ is convergent . if $(a_n)$ is convergent then $(a_{2n}-a_n)$ is convergent to zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> 1.If $(a_{2n} -a_n)$ is convergent to zero then $(a_n)$ is convergent. True/False?
>
> 2.If $(a_n)$ is convergent then $(a_{2n}-a_n)$ is convergent. True/False?

I solved $2$ this way - let $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }a_n  =L$ and $(a_{2n})$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$ then they must converge to the same limit , therefore $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }a_{2n}  =L$ so we get that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }a_{2n}- a_n  =L-L=0$ so the statement is True

for the first part I know that the statement is not true but I cannot find a counterexample or a general way to show it , the practice book used this counterexample and explanation: let $a_n=\begin{cases}
  1 &\text{if $n=2^k$ $k \in \Bbb N$}\\ 
 0&\text{otherwise}\\ 
\end{cases}$

if $n=2^k$ then for $k \in \Bbb N$  we get $2n=2^{k+1}$ therefore $a_{2n}=a_n=1$ and $a_{2n}-a_n=0$

if $n\not=2^k$ then $a_{2n}=a_n=0$ and $a_{2n}-a_n=0$ meaning for all $n$ we get $a_{2n}-a_n=0$ so
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }a_{2n}- a_n  =0$ but $(a_n)$ is not convergent

$(a_{2n-1})$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$ in the odd indexes so $(a_{2n-1})=0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }a_{2n-1}=0$. the sequence $n_k =2^k$ is a sequence that is stricly increasing of natural indexes because for all $k$ we get $2^k$ is also a natural number and
$n_{k+1}=2^{k+1}=2\cdot2^k <2^k =n_k$ , we get that $(a_{n_k})=(a_{2^k})$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$ but all of its elements are the same $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }a_{2^k}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }1=1$ but this subsequence has a different limit which means that $(a_n)$ is not convergent and the statement is false

my question is if there is another way to show this? this counterexample seems too complicated , I understand the explanations but I would not have figured to use $a_n=\begin{cases}
  1 &\text{if $n=2^k$ $k \in \Bbb N$}\\ 
 0&\text{otherwise}\\ 
\end{cases}$  .. is there another counterexample? or a general way to show this other than the way they did in the book?

thank you

Comment: The counterexample here is not complicated.  This is fussing too much.  Just claim (i) the sequence $\{a_n\}$ clearly diverges, (ii) but, since $a_{2n}-a_n=0$ for all $n$ the sequence $\{a_{2n}-a_n\}$ converges.   If pressed for (i) just point out that $a_1,a_3,a_5 \dots \to 0$ but $a_2, a_4,a_8, \dots \to 1$.  If pressed for (ii) just say it is bloody obvious.  Seriously, though, once you fully understand this simple example, express your answer in a minimal way without so much notation and simple computations.  E.g.,  "if $n$ is a power of 2 so is $2n$, hence $a_{2n}=a_n$" etc.

Comment: The example, as stated, does look complicated and I can understand why you respond this way.  Your goal is to look at such things and see why they are actually simple and why someone (human) would think of such an (inhuman) example.  Reduce the ideas to this simple form:  "For all $n$, $a_{2n}-a_n=0$ so this is a convergent sequence. Why?  If $n$ is a power of $2$ then so is $2n$ which means that $a_{2n}=a_n=1$, but if $n$ is not a power of $2$ then neither is $2n$ so $a_{2n}=a_n=0$."   A detailed string of computations and subsequences misses the point.  Work towards simplicity.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson As I said I really appreciate all the help and you are right this is exactly what I want to know .. these counterexamples seem "inhuman" or like an example that only someone who knew the answer to would think about it.. how could someone think of $n=2^k$ .. this is what I thought when I first saw it . I am aware that with time I will also pick it up but for now it seems impossible to me. I will take what you said and keep it in mind "a detailed string of computations and subsequences misses the point"

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Again thank you , but as Isaid before what is easy and obvious for you might not be for others. I get what you are saying and you are 100% right. but for example in this case I still don't know how they thought about the power of 2 thing. but I did learn from you a new way to write things in a more simple way and more direct which is better :)

Comment: The guy who made this up probably thought this way. Hmmm. Don't want $a_{2n}−a_n$ to be very complicated. How about zero? So I need $a_1=a_2=a_4=a_8=\dots$ Then I can do similar stuff with $ a_3,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_9\dots$.  Powers of two definitely the key.   Now how to write this up in a cute compact form without giving the whole game away in this textbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the odd part of a positive integer to be its greatest odd factor (you can get it by dividing the largest possible power of $2$ out of the integer). For instance, $48 = 2^4\cdot 3$, so the odd part of $48$ is $3$.

For any integer $n$, the odd part of $2n$ is equal to the odd part of $n$. Also the odd part of any odd number is the odd number itself; so odd parts take on arbitrarily large values.

If you define your sequence by $a_n$ is the odd part of $n$, you get a divergent sequence for which $a_{2n}-a_n=0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler counterexample is given by
$$a_n = \log(\log(n))$$

Comment: Thank you I should have noted that I am still at the beginning of the course and haven't learned logarithms yet (not allowed to use yet)